# How to understand the use of supertypes and variance in Scala's Option?

Tags: scala, types, scala-collections, variance, type-bounds

Specifically, looking at `getOrElse`.

Scala's `Option` is defined to be covariant in `A` like this:

```
sealed abstract class Option[+A] extends Product with Serializable {
  self =>
  @inline final def getOrElse[B >: A](default: => B): B =
    if (isEmpty) default else this.get
}
```

The definition of `getOrElse` seems to imply a supertype of `A` must be returned, which doesn't necessarily make a lot of sense to me.  But in fact, it looks like anything goes: subtype or supertype.

```
scala> class A
// defined class A
scala> class B extends A
// defined class B
scala> val optA: Option[A] = Option(null)
val optA: Option[A] = None
scala> optA.getOrElse(new B)
val res23: A = B@66a2c8e7
scala> class C extends B
// defined class C
scala> val optB: Option[B] = Option(null)
val optB: Option[B] = None
scala> optB.getOrElse(new A)
val res24: A = A@2a460bf
scala> optB.getOrElse(new C)
val res25: B = C@e87f97f
```

How is this possible, given the constraints? Specifically, I don't get how `optB.getOrElse(new C)` is allowed given the constraints on `getOrElse` (it should return a supertype of Option's type parameter).

Comment: Think of it like the ternary operator /`if (c) new A else new B`.

Comment: So it inherits the type of the l-value (if there is one)? OK, kind of makes sense. But I still don't get how `optB.getOrElse(new C)` is allowed given the constraints on getOrElse (it should return a supertype of Option's type parameter). I'll amend my question.

Comment: Well, if you look at the type of `res25` as printed, it says the type is `B` which seems to be perfectly sound. The greatest common supertype of its operands.

Comment: expr `new C` whose type is C is implicit converted to type `B`

Comment: Ah, I see, just using the basic property that any type can be viewed as a super type of itself without issue.

Comment: @bbarker that's part of it. But consider `val o = Some(new A).getOrElse(new Object)`. It goes both ways. And it can because the signature of `getOrElse` is designed to enable a supertype of `this` to be specified such that the static type of the result will be widened to that supertype. That is sound because it cannot be used unsafely. Just like `val o = if(true) new A else new Object`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not "everything goes", look closer at the inferred types of the return values.

The declaration `B >: A` means: the compiler will infer the most specific type `B` such that the argument to `getOrElse` is of type `B` and simultaneously `A` is a subtype of `B`. This is another way to say: the return type of `getOrElse` is the *least upper bound* of both the parameter of `Option` and the type of the fallback-argument.

Your experiments confirm just that:

```
scala> class A
scala> class B extends A
scala> class C extends B

scala> val optA: Option[A] = Option(null)
scala> optA.getOrElse(new B)
val res23: A = B@66a2c8e7                 // LUB(A, B) = A

scala> val optB: Option[B] = Option(null)
scala> optB.getOrElse(new A)
val res24: A = A@2a460bf                  // LUB(B, A) = A, symmetric!

scala> optB.getOrElse(new C)
val res25: B = C@e87f97f                  // LUB(B, C) = B
```

The last case is of course completely valid, because `new C` is of type `C`, and since `C <: B`, it is *also* an element of type `B`. There is no contradiction: `B` is the inferred *return type*, it's *not* the most specific type of the argument `default` (this would be `default.type`, which is mostly useless when used directly). In particular, `A` does not have to be subtype of `default.type`, this wouldn't make any sense.

If you would systematically do all experiments with combinations of A, B, C, you would get the following return types:

```
  | A B C
--+-----
A | A A A
B | A B B
C | A B C
```

This is essentially the "maximum"-function on the totally ordered set with elements `C <: B <: A`.

The simple & intuitive rule is: the compiler and the function signatures of the methods in the standard library try really hard to provide the most specific return type, and to preserve as much type information as possible.

Comment: I don't understand the total ordering `A <: B <: C`. Does this read A is a subtype of B is a subtype of C? If so, how is that possible? If C extends B and B extends A, then doesn't that mean C is a subtype of B and B is a subtype of A, which would make the ordering `C <: B <: A`?

Comment: @DaltonSweeney Yeah, you're right, I flipped the order of `A, B, C` for some reason. Here, `C` is subtype of `B`, and `B` is subtype of `A`, not the other way round. Fixed. Thank you!